# Conditions for an integral operator to be a compact operator on L^2(R)

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators, integral-operators

I think Conditions for an integral operator to be a compact operator on L^2(R). I know there are some conditions such as Hilbert-Schmidt integral operator is compact. However, do there exist other conditions under which an integral operator can be determined to be a compact operator on L^2(R)?